# How to inactivate items in a table using MVC 3, EF Model First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Im using MVC 3, EF Model first for my web application.

I have a table with a list of employees, I want to be able to inactivate employees and also be able to delete employees. I have no problems with deleting employees but I also want to be able to inactivate employees so people cant seach for the employee or use em in other type of functionality, though, I still want them to exist in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add status field to the table. Employee will have different status 1 - Online 2 - Inactive 3 - Deleted. this way you can keep all your employees in database but you'll be able to pull out employees that are only currently hired(online).

`Context.Get().Employees.Where(x => x.Status == EmployeeStatus.Online);`

And EmployeeStatus enum:

```
public enum EmployeeStatus
{
Online = 1,
Inactive = 2,
Deleted = 3,
}
```

EDIT:

You may need to do some additional parsing to get the enum to work that way; on the other hand, you can just use pull data by int value but enum is much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't matter with using EF or ADO.net to inactivate items (soft delete). What I usually do is put a flag something like "record_status" in database and change the status when I want to soft DELETE the record. 
In the SELECT or UPDATE operation, I check this "record_status" column and do require operation.